# Header file in c++

Tags: c++

Header file for the following error :
 **undefined reference to `swimmingPool::timeNeeded(int)'**

I am making some trivial error in the code but not able to make out what.Relatively new to the language.Please help !!

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstdio>
    #include "swimmingPool.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "Pool Data: " << endl;
        swimmingPool p(30,15,10,0,0);
        int rate_in;
        cout << "   Length: " << p.length << endl;
        cout << "   Width: "<< p.width << endl;
        cout << "   Depth: "<< p.depth << endl;
        cout << "   Total water in the pool: " << p.water_initially <<endl;
        cout << "To completely fill the pool" << endl;
        cout << "   Enter water fill in rate: ";
        cin >> rate_in;

        cout<< endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Time to fill the pool is approximately: " <<                         p.timeNeeded(rate_in)/3600 << " hours and "<<
        p.timeNeeded(rate_in)%60<< " minutes."<<endl;
        return 0;

    }


    /**********************************************************************************/
    /******************** swimmingPool.h         **********************************************/

    #ifndef __IH__
    #define __IH__

    class swimmingPool{
    public:
        int length;
        int width;
        int depth;
        int rate_out;
        int water_initially;
        int waterNeeded();
        int timeNeeded(int in);
        swimmingPool(int a,int b, int c, int d,int e){}

    };

    #endif

    /********************************************************************************/
    /******************************** swimmingPoolImp.cpp ****************************/
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstdio>
    #include "swimmingPool.h"

    swimmingPool::swimmingPool(int a,int b, int c, int d,int e) //IT has five         parameters for length/breadth/height/water_initially/rate_out.Rate to be taken input from         user.
    {
            length = a;
            width = b;
            depth = c;
            rate_out = d;
            water_initially = e;
    }

    int swimmingPool::waterNeeded()
    {
        return( length*width*depth - water_initially)*7.48; //conversion factor
    }

    int swimmingPool::timeNeeded(int rate_in)
    {
            if(rate_in > rate_out)
            {
                return (( waterNeeded() / (rate_in - rate_out))*60);
            }
            else
            {
                return (( waterNeeded() / (rate_out - rate_in))*60);
            }
    };
```

Comment: what compiler do yo use?if you don't use an IDE that links automatically other translation units you must compile swimingPoolImp.cpp alone and then link manually the main program with it

Comment: swimmingPool(int a,int b, int c, int d,int e){} this is also a definition of the constructor. You seem to have 2 definitions of the constructor. Have only one definition of it and try again the compilation.

Comment: @YogiJoshi .. but the header file ought to contain one overloaded constructor definition ?

Comment: @EmilCondrea I am using code blocks.

Comment: the constructors are not overloaded as they have the same signature. Also, as pointed by @njaard, you might not be actually linking the object of .cpp file which contains class functions or it might also happen that compiler, you are using, gives the error of undefined reference because of multiple definitions. Can you show how you are linking?

Comment: As an aside, names containing two or more consecutive underscores are reserved in C++ (as are names which start with an underscore and an uppercase letter, and any name starting with an underscore in global scope). Your code therefore has undefined behaviour due to `#define __IH__`. This is unlikely causing you any problems, but you should nonetheless change it (and avoid it in future).

Comment: Just figured it out ... IDE was not linking it properly !! 
Thankyou @YogiJoshi

Comment: @user87071 You should accept the answer which best addressed the problem (in this case, njaard's), and *upvote* other answers which were also helpful. As it stands, you've accepted an answer which wasn't actually for the problem you posted (but fixed a different problem in your code).

Comment: @JBentley I am sorry sir, I am new to this forum. I'll make necessary changes. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message in the category "undefined reference to..." generally means that the function, compiled or otherwise was not *linked* into your executable.

First, make sure that the object file for swimmingPool.cpp (swimmingPool.o or or windows, swimmingPool.obj) was linked into your program.

If you've confirmed that, then it's possible that your make tool forgot to recompile swimmingPool.cpp after you added timeNeeded, and therefor that object file is out of date. You should recompile swimmingPool.cpp if that's the case.

The specific commands necessary to do this depends on your toolchain.

Also, your functions are not "const-correct" and you should look that up soon as you learn.

Comment: can you try running it on your system please ?

Comment: No. Also, Yogi Joshi is correct - I think you're not compiling and linking swimmingPoolImp.cpp at all, otherwise you should also get a "multiple definition error".

Answer (score 1):

Resolve multiple definitions of the constructor (one in header and other in cpp file)

```
swimmingPool(int a,int b, int c, int d,int e){} // **this makes it a definition and not just declaration**

swimmingPool::swimmingPool(int a,int b, int c, int d,int e) //IT has five         parameters for length/breadth/height/water_initially/rate_out.Rate to be taken input from         user.
    {
            length = a;
            width = b;
            depth = c;
            rate_out = d;
            water_initially = e;
    }
```

Change `swimmingPool(int a,int b, int c, int d,int e){}` to `swimmingPool(int a,int b, int c, int d,int e);`

Comment: Now an additional error along with the first one:
undefined reference to `swimmingPool::swimmingPool(int, int, int, int, int)'

Comment: @user87071 It sounds like your IDE is not linking your two source files into your binary.

Comment: As a simple fix put the definitions of the functions into header file or do appropriate linking while creating the executable.